# Maven in eclipse not showing all folders

Tags: eclipse, maven

I am new to Maven and have been trying to get a project working with Eclipse, hibernate,Maven and mysql. I am stuck at the very first step. I have everything configured properly i think and if i create a new Maven project in eclipse it does not show me any folder under src/main or src/test. although if i go back to that folder in the workspace it has a src/main/java

FUrthermore the src/main/resources folder is not created at the time of project creation?

Any clue what the problem maybe or how i can fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: have u checked your build path? Does it include src/main?

Comment: Wait. Is it a new project from scratch, or it's an existing project but you are only new to Eclipse m2e? In the latter case you have to import existing Maven project. Right click on the empty project area, and Import Existing Maven projects from context menu.

Answer (score 1):

For your first problem, when you create a new Maven project the folders that get created depend on the archetype you choose.  Assuming you chose quickstart, then it does create (assuming you chose `com.example` as your package in the wizard and `example-project` as your artifactId):

[image]

And it configures the project so that `/src/main/java` is in the Build Path.  That said, if you are viewing your project in the Package Explorer view, then the packages are shown outside of the folder structure.  So, you would see the the `com.example.example_project` package containing `App.java` in the build folder `/src/main/java` and you would see the `com.example.example_project` package containing `AppTest.java` in the build folder `/src/test/java`.  These would show up above the libraries which is above non-build folders which is where you see the `src` folder.

To answer your second question, no, `/src/main/resources` is not generated assuming you chose the quickstart archetype (this is governed by the quickstart archetype and does the same thing whether generated in eclipse or on the command line).

And third, to fix this (I assume you mean add the resources folder), find the `src/java` folder (below the libraries), right click and choose New->Folder.  Name it resources.  Then right click your project, choose Maven->Update Project.  This will cause maven eclipse to reconfigure the project according to the Maven configuration which will result in the `/src/main/resources` being added to the build path.  As such, it will get moved above the libraries next to `/src/main/java` and `/src/test/java`.

Comment: Thank you Lucus. I figured out my problems through your reply.

Comment: i am trying to implement the code in the below link http://www.itinpractice.com/tutorials/499/pessimistic-locking-example.html  but am unsuccessful uptil now. I am done with initial setup on maven,hibernate etc. Could you tell me what topics i should read to properly copy the different type of classes and make the example work.

Comment: That tutorial looks pretty complete.  If it is not enough for you, try the [hibernate documentation](http://www.hibernate.org/docs.html).